# VBA Macro Loop only indexing once

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have some VBA code that is supposed to update projected hours for each staffer on a project. Staff names are in cells B10:B32 and based on the number of populated cells in the range it's supposed to pull a unique ID for the staffer and project (held in named cells employee1, employee2, etc.) and paste the new hours and billing rate on the corresponding row of data sheet ("wsDest"). If the staff member is new then it is supposed to paste all the project info on the last row of the data sheet.

The macro is completing but only seems to be affecting the first staff member in the list. Is something wrong with how I define the loop?

```
For i = 1 To WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Edit Project").Range("B10:B32"))

    'Fill string variable with string of text to be matched
    uniqueid = Range("employee" & i)
     
    'Loop through each cell in range
    For Each c In rng
    'Check if cell value matches the string to be matched
        If UCase(c.Value) = UCase(uniqueid) Then
    'Check if this is the first match (new range hasn't been filled yet)
            If myRng Is Nothing Then
    'Fill new range with cell
                Set myRng = c
            Else
    'Join new matching cell together with previously found matches
                Set myRng = Application.Union(myRng, c)
            End If
        End If
    Next c
     
    If myRng Is Nothing Then
        DestRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
        wsCopy.Range("C3").Copy
            wsDest.Range("B" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("C4:D4").Copy
            wsDest.Range("C" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("E4").Copy
            wsDest.Range("F" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("G4:K4").Copy
            wsDest.Range("H" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("staff" & i).Copy
            wsDest.Range("E" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("rate" & i).Copy
            wsDest.Range("M" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("newrate" & i).Copy
            wsDest.Range("O" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("newhours" & i).Copy
            wsDest.Range("R" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
        wsCopy.Range("F5").Copy
            wsDest.Range("G" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
    Else
        DestRow = myRng.Row
        
        Range("newrate" & i).Copy
            wsDest.Range("O" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
            
        Range("newhours" & i).Copy
            wsDest.Range("R" & DestRow).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: you should start by check what `WorksheetFunction.CountA(Worksheets("Edit Project").Range("B10:B32"))` is evaluating to. There is probably a much better way to get your upper bound for iterating.

Answer (score 0):

I had not cleared the object "myRng" at the end of each iteration, so it was not looking for a new row.